# MongDB multiple file uploads

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mean-stack, nosql

Here I have a doubt. I want to create a db which stores the user data (i.e) username, password , etc;

It also includes the images the user uploaded. I'm okay if it saves a single image, all I've to do is to create a field name image and saves its path. But the question is what if the user uploads more images, in which format i can store the image? do i need to create multiple fields for multiple images??? Definitely its not the solution.

I want the best solution for storing multiple images for an user and fetch it back from the database to reflect it back in browser.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to store data within users collection only, then you can have images field as a array of object

```
{
  "userName" : "name of user",
  "password": "password of user",
  "images": [
      {
       //image 1 properties 
      },
      {
      //image N properties 
      }
  ],
 //more user properties
}
```